# Laravel get records without calling "all()"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have been scratching my head over this one, hopefully a super simple answer.

I am using andrewelkins' (excellent!) start site to learn the ways of Laravel, which can be found over at https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site. This starter-site is a simple blog-system, to get to know Laravel.

In one of the controllers (to be specific: AdminBlogsController.php) I see the following code:

```
public function getIndex()
    {
    // Title
    $title = Lang::get('admin/blogs/title.blog_management');

    //Grab all the blog posts
    $posts = $this->post;

    // Show the page
    return View::make('admin/blogs/index', compact('posts', 'title'));
}
```

What bothers me, how can you call `$this->post` without calling something like `all();` to get all records.

In every other tutorial I see something like `$this->post->all()`, but not here. Do note, that this code without the `all()` works.

Comment: The question is: does it work? No, it doesn't. Whole controller is a mess, and this particular code is not fetching anything from the DB. In order to do so it would read `$this->post->get();` otherwise it's just empty `Post` model.

Comment: When I run this code, I do get the posts in the view. How is andrewelkins able to get all the records in the view, without making a DB call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is broken and the comment is misleading. The view does **not** receive any posts. To verify, search [the view](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/blob/master/app/views/admin/blogs/index.blade.php) for the `$post` variable. You won't find it, because it's not being used at all.

So then how *do* the posts render on the page?

Simple answer: **AJAX**.

The posts are not present on initial page load. Rather, they're [loaded in through AJAX](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/blob/master/app/views/admin/blogs/index.blade.php#L51) from [this controller method](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/blob/master/app/controllers/admin/AdminBlogsController.php#L224-L241), where you can clearly see the database calls!

Comment: Ah, so there you have it.. The actual DB query. The comment really is misleading. Convention over configuration, I can live with that, but this felt like voodoo.